# trying to track an object, bounding box jitters

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, moviepy, yolov8, object-tracking

I am trying to write a python script that can convert a 16:9 video into a 9:16 while keeping the region of interest in frame. I am having trouble on how to do this in a well manner. My current approach is to use YOLO object reconition every 120 frames and crop around it. This works for the most part, but the end video is very choppy as there is no transition between the frames. How can I go about fixing this, or is there a better way to accomplish this task?

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
from ultralytics import YOLO
import numpy as np
import cv2

model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")
clip = VideoFileClip("Mack Falls Off Cliff.mp4")


def apply_mask(frame, bbox):
    height, width, _ = frame.shape
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = [int(val) for val in bbox]

    # Calculate the aspect ratio of the bounding box
    bbox_width = x2 - x1
    bbox_height = y2 - y1
    bbox_aspect_ratio = bbox_width / bbox_height

    # Determine the crop region based on the desired 9:16 aspect ratio
    if bbox_aspect_ratio > 9 / 16:
        # Crop horizontally
        new_width = int(bbox_height * (9 / 16))
        x1 = x1 + int((bbox_width - new_width) / 2)
        x2 = x1 + new_width
    else:
        # Crop vertically
        new_height = int(bbox_width * (16 / 9))
        y1 = y1 + int((bbox_height - new_height) / 2)
        y2 = y1 + new_height

    # Extract the cropped region and resize to the desired 9:16 resolution
    cropped_frame = frame[y1:y2, x1:x2]
    masked_frame = cv2.resize(cropped_frame, (720, 1280))
    return masked_frame


prev_bbox = None
frame_count = 0
crop_interval = 120


def process_frame(frame):
    global prev_bbox, frame_count

    if frame_count % crop_interval == 0:
        results = model(frame)
        bboxes = results[0].boxes.xyxy.cpu().numpy()

        if len(bboxes) > 0:
            bbox = max(bboxes, key=lambda x: (x[2] - x[0]) * (x[3] - x[1]))
            if prev_bbox is not None:
                bbox = smooth_bbox(prev_bbox, bbox)
            prev_bbox = bbox
            masked_frame = apply_mask(frame, bbox)
        else:
            if prev_bbox is not None:
                masked_frame = apply_mask(frame, prev_bbox)
            else:
                masked_frame = frame
    else:
        if prev_bbox is not None:
            masked_frame = apply_mask(frame, prev_bbox)
        else:
            masked_frame = frame

    frame_count += 1
    return masked_frame


def smooth_bbox(prev_bbox, curr_bbox, smoothing_factor=0.95):
    smooth_bbox = [
        int(prev_val * smoothing_factor + curr_val * (1 - smoothing_factor))
        for prev_val, curr_val in zip(prev_bbox, curr_bbox)
    ]
    return smooth_bbox


processed_clip = clip.fl_image(process_frame)
processed_clip.write_videofile("output_video1.mp4")
```

Comment: show us "choppy". what is the ROI? why does this involve deep learning at all? are you ***tracking*** something? then calling this "cropping" undersells the problem. nor would this appropriately be called a "moviepy" problem. I've adjusted the tags and title. feel free to fix the question body. you might want to ***filter the track*** (smoothing/lowpass). this will require two passes over the video: tracking, then generating the video. if you need this to work in realtime, then you need to think about the filtering much more (kalman filter).

Comment: ROI is the region of interest in the original video. Basically when I change aspect ratios, the main object may no longer be in frame, so I am using YOLO to classify the object, and re-center the footage (every 120 frames). If I cold upload videos, I can show you waht the output video looks like, but basically the reposition of the frame every 120 seconds looks very jittery. I guess cause theres no keyframe transition, between repositions.